# Numpad buttons going weird

Tags: gnome, keyboard, numpad

I have this issue with my number pad, that when I press the <kbd>/</kbd> instead of giving me the expected `/`, it gives a `∕`. Note that the unwanted slash is slightly more tilted than the expected one. Also, <kbd>*</kbd> gives ⋅, and <kbd>-</kbd> gives−. The <kbd>+</kbd> seems to work fine.

Using [this website](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html), I can determine that the faulty keys do give different values than expected.

```
∕ : Division Slash (Solidus)
⋅ : Dot Operator (Asterisk)
− : Minus Sign (Hyphen-Minus)
```

I put the wanted character in brackets. It seems that my numpad is in some kind of math mode. I don't want to remap the keys to the wanted value, I instead want to fix the problem, this should be possible, as the problem first occurred a while ago while typing math equations in gedit.

**EDIT:**
The same thing happens with the <kbd>.</kbd> button on the numpad giving `,` instead of the expected `.`

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS, with a Dell SK-8115 keyboard.

If I go to my system settings, my keyboard layout is English (US). If I view the layout I see this:[image] If you look on the numpad's period key, it shows a `,` above the `Del` text, instead of the wanted period. For the other key, it shows multiple values, e.g. the <kbd>/</kbd> shows two slashes, and a division symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

If I ran `dconf-editor` in the terminal, nagivated to `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`, this window would show up:
[image]

The `xkb-options` had some values in it, after clicking `Set to Default`, the values were deleted, and my buttons were restored to what I wanted them to do.